# Get all values and nested values that match a key name

Tags: json, nested, key, jq

I have some data that looks like:

```
{
  "hello": {
     "foo": "x",
     "y": "z"
  },
  "foo": "a",
  "bar": {
    {
      "foo": "b"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get all values with key `foo`, wherever they are?

Answer (score 2):

You can search using [recursive decent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..)

#### Solution

```
jq '..|.foo?'
```

#### Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/Xp64LfJFBc

#### Documentation

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..